# CS50 substitution - Loop not working for length of plaintext

Tags: cs50

I am trying to create a loop for the length of the plaintext and converting the plaintext to alphabetic index so that i can get a pointer to the same location in argv[].However the loop only seems to be running for plain[0] and only getting the equivalent key for argv[0] (which is the key). Any help would be much appreciated.

```c
string plain = get_string("plaintext: ");//prompt user for text

printf("ciphertext: ");

int lenp = strlen(plain);//get length of text

int c;

char* p;

for (int q = 0; q < lenp; q++)
{

    if (isalpha(plain[q]))
    {
        if (isupper(plain[q]))
        {
            //covert from ASCII to alpabetic index

            h = plain[q] - 65;

            //pointer to the equivalent element in argv[]

            p = &argv[1][h];

            *p = argv[1][h];

            c = *p;
```

Comment: this seems like partial code, the `if` clauses and the `for` block doesn't close, did you forget to add the closing braces `}`?

Comment: Actually you were right, i tidied it up and it works now, thanks for the help